# What is the complement of an element of a generated σ-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading Halmos' *Measure Theory*. As a newbie, I got confused by how to write out a complement of an element of a generated σ-algebra.

For example, let $Ω$ is a set of points(such as $\mathbb N$  or something like that), $F$ is a σ-algebra on $Ω$ and $C = \{ A_1, A_2, A_3,...\}$ is a countable partition of $Ω$(means $A_n ∩ A_m = \emptyset$ for $n ≠ m$ and $\cup_{n} A_n = Ω$). $σ(F \cup C)$ denotes the generated σ-algebra by $F \cup C$. Suppose $X$ is an arbitrary element of $σ(F \cup C)$(that is $X ∈ σ( F \cup C)$) and we does have $X^c ∈ σ(F \cup C)$ according to properties of generated σ-algebra. But what does $X^c$ mean? (I mean I'm not sure which set will be used for getting complement of $X$ coz $X$ may contain elements that do not belong to $Ω$.) Is it equal to $Ω$ substract $X$?

Comment: $X$ has to be a subset of $\Omega$ (this is part of what it means to be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$), and yes, $X^\mathsf{c}=\Omega\setminus X$.

Comment: @Hayden: No no no. I mean $X ∈ σ( F \cup C)$. Does this imply $X$ be a subset of $Ω$?

Comment: @Hayden $σ(F \cup C)$ is a family of subsets of $\Omega$, which means $X$ is indeed a subset of $\Omega$.

Comment: @ivanhoescott: I got your idea. Hayden is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem got solved. I cite Hayden's comment(the 1st comment) as an answer so that I can close it:

"$X$ has to be a subset of $Ω$ (this is part of what it means to be a σ-algebra on $Ω$), and yes, $X^c = Ω - X$".